# Call a web service with JSON payload from jaggery

Tags: wso2-api-manager, jaggery-js

I'm trying to call a rest web service which accept JSON payload from WSO2 store jaggery app. 
I used WSRequest and it is allowed to send only xml payload.
Is there any way which we can call a web service with a JSON payload from jaggery.

Comment: This can be done using XMLHttpRequest.  `var url = '<url>'; 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type" , "text/plain");
  xhr.send(payload);
  var response = xhr.responseText;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jaggery post[1] as well.

[1] - http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=post